# Filtering with jQuery "find" and "filter" with multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to make some filter options for a page on a clients website with multiple dropdown menus. I can make it work, but it will always reset the filtering when I select an option. I need them to work "together". It's for filtering rooms in a hotel (not a lot of rooms there).

So the first dropdown is the number of persons that can fit in a room, then the type of room to rent, and finally the number of bedrooms in that room/house.

A user can user all 3 dropdowns to filter his results, or he can use only 1. Whatever he likes. He must be able to select "3" in the first dropdown, then it filters everything to show only rooms with up to "3" in the results box. After, if he selects "Studios" in the second dropdown, it needs to keep in mind he has selected "3" for the number of persons that fits in the room, but also the keep in mind that he just selected "Studios" now, so it should display Studios that can have up to 3 persons. etc.

I think you get the idea.
Here's my HTML code:

```
<select class="bedroom-min">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select class="type">
  <option value="all">Select...</option>
  <option value="casitas">Casitas</option>
  <option value="studios">Studios</option>
  <option value="dorm">Dorm</option>
</select>

<select class="bedrooms">
  <option value="all">Select...</option>
  <option value="1">1 bedroom</option>
  <option value="2">2 bedrooms</option>
</select>

<div class="property-load-section">
  <div class="property-item" data-bedrooms="5" data-type="casitas" data-bed="1">Room #529</div>
  <div class="property-item" data-bedrooms="4" data-type="studios" data-bed="2">Room #737</div>
  <div class="property-item" data-bedrooms="3" data-type="dorm" data-bed="2">Room #123</div>
  <div class="property-item" data-bedrooms="2" data-type="studios" data-bed="2">Room #126</div>
  <div class="property-item" data-bedrooms="1" data-type="casitas" data-bed="1">Room #523</div>
</div>
```

And here's the jQuery code :

```
//Filtering for number of person that can sleep in that room
$("select").change(function() {
  var minValue = $('select.bedroom-min').val();
  $('.property-load-section').find('.property-item').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-bedrooms') < minValue;
  }).fadeOut('fast');
  $('.property-load-section').find('.property-item').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-bedrooms') >= minValue;
  }).fadeIn('fast');
});

//Filtering for type of rooms
$("select.type").change(function() {
    var roomType = $('select.type').val();
  $('.property-load-section').find('.property-item').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-type') != roomType;
  }).fadeOut('fast');
});

//Filtering for the number of bedrooms
$("select.bedrooms").change(function() {
    var roomBed = $('select.bedrooms').val();
  $('.property-load-section').find('.property-item').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-bed') != roomBed;
  }).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Here's a CodePen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRxXVK?editors=1010

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm pretty new to javascript/jQuery. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend doing the same logic for each select's change event and in that logic you should check for all of the three filtering options at once. In the cases of *type* and *bedrooms* the value `"all"` should also be taken into consideration as it is a special value which will not be equal to the `data-` attributes you set.

With that said here is the modified  JavaScript code:

```
//call the same function for each select's change event
$("select.bedroom-min, select.type, select.bedrooms").change(updateRooms);

function updateRooms() {
  //get all the values
  var minValue = $('select.bedroom-min').val();
  var roomType = $('select.type').val();
  var roomBed = $('select.bedrooms').val();

  $('.property-load-section')
    .find('.property-item')
    .hide()
    .filter(function () {
      var okMinBedrooms = $(this).attr('data-bedrooms') >= minValue;

      var okRoomType = true;
      if(roomType !== "all"){
        okRoomType = $(this).attr('data-type') === roomType;
      }

      var okRoomBed = true;
      if(roomBed !== "all"){
        okRoomBed = $(this).attr('data-bed') === roomBed;
      }

      //only fade a room if it satisfies all three conditions
      return okMinBedrooms && okRoomType && okRoomBed;
  }).fadeIn('fast');
}
```

And a CodePen [link](https://codepen.io/botimoo/pen/rwZXQe).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for explaining what I need to do here. Everything is clearer now. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pjz958n6/.

```
$("select").change(function() {
  var minValue = $('select.bedroom-min').val();
  var roomType = $('select.type').val();
  var roomBed = $('select.bedrooms').val();

  $('.property-load-section').find('.property-item').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-bedrooms') < minValue 
            || ($(this).attr('data-type') != roomType || roomType == "all")
            || ($(this).attr('data-bed') != roomBed || roomBed == "all");
  }).fadeOut('fast');
  $('.property-load-section').find('.property-item').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-bedrooms') >= minValue 
            && ($(this).attr('data-type') == roomType || roomType == "all")
            && ($(this).attr('data-bed') == roomBed || roomBed == "all");
  }).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

All you need to do is just evaluate all the `select` options on change of any. The similar for `fade-out`, just that you need to do an `||` contrary to `&&` in `fade-in`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed JavaScript code or [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AmitKB/yg0s42Ly/) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Once document is ready

    // Reference to dropdowns
    var ddlRooms = $('select.bedroom-min');
    var ddlType = $('select.type');
    var ddlBedRooms = $('select.bedrooms');

    // Hook up event handler for change event
    ddlRooms.change( doFilter );
    ddlType.change( doFilter );
    ddlBedRooms.change( doFilter );

    // Start with initial filtering
    doFilter();

    function doFilter(){

        // Start with hiding all property item
        $('.property-load-section > .property-item').hide();

        // Get the selected values
        var selectedRooms = parseInt(ddlRooms.val());
        var selectedType = ddlType.val();
        var selectedBedRooms = ddlBedRooms.val();


        // Get items matching rooms
        var matched = $('.property-load-section').find('.property-item').filter(function () {

            // Current property item
            var curPropertyItem = $(this)

            var curPropertyRooms = parseInt(curPropertyItem.attr('data-bedrooms'))
            var curPropertyType = curPropertyItem.attr('data-type');
            var curPropertyBeds = curPropertyItem.attr('data-bed');

            //console.log('Rooms matched: ' + roomMatched());
            //console.log('Type matched: ' + roomTypMatched());
            //console.log('Beds matched: ' + bedsMatched())

            return ( roomMatched() && roomTypMatched() && bedsMatched() );

            function roomMatched(){
                return curPropertyRooms >= selectedRooms;
            }

            function roomTypMatched(){
                if ( selectedType === 'all' ){
                    return true;
                }
                else if( curPropertyType === selectedType ){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function bedsMatched(){

                if( selectedBedRooms === 'all' ){
                    return true;
                }
                else if ( curPropertyBeds === selectedBedRooms ){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }           
        });

        // Show matched property
        //console.log('Matched items: ' + matched.length);
        matched.show();
    }   
})
```